# sql query question makes me confused please

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following two relational schemas, the EMPLOYEE relational schema records the employee number (ssn), age (age) and the department (dno), the primary key is ssn, and the DEPARTMENT relational schema records the department number (dnum ) and name (dname), The primary key is dnum, in which the foreign key "dno" of EMPLOYEE refers to the primary key "dnum" of DEPARTMENT,

please use SQL GROUP BY to write the query ''For each department that has more than two employees, retrieve the department name and the number of its employees who each is more than twenty-five years old)”.

Thank you guys

Comment: you need to think, Clue: theres a having count >2 somewhere in the query :)

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You can always start simple. Such as, first see if you can get all departments with more than two employees. And then take one of these departments and see if you can get the ages of its employees. Then try to get only the employees who are more than 25 years old. So, step by step making progress... and finally consider how to put it all together for a final result that answers the question.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Sounding like you are new to databases, DO NOT use SSN as a primary key.  Such private data should NOT be commonly accessible.  Make an auto-increment number the primary key.  Use that for all subsequent tables.  Use the SSN only if NEEDED as a search to find the auto-increment value and use that auto-increment value to be used in all others.  Otherwise, you have SSNs posted all over.  What if fraud and multiple people provide same SSN.  Use can use to pre-qualify for distinct before adding, but dont use as basis to all tables joined to.

Answer (score -1):

You can use as approach. It's not exactly your tables but you can easy match it tot your structure:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM DEPARTMENTS D
JOIN EMPLOYEES E USING (DEPARTMENT_ID)
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME
HAVING COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) > 2
;
```

[format sql online](https://sqlize.online/s/x)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT d.dname, count(e.ssn) as cnt
FROM Employee e JOIN department d 
on e.dno = d.dnum
WHERE e.age> = 25 
Group BY e.dname
HAVING COUNT(ssn) >= 2;
```

Comment: sorry but it seems has an error: 
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where em.age> = 25 having count(em.ssn) >= 2 LIMIT 100' at line 6
Error Code: ER_PARSE_ERROR